# Having Trouble Serializing Data

Tags: java, swing, serialization, io

I Am having trouble saving the state of a Form application and loading its state.  I created a simple Swing Application in Java using netbeans.  The purpose of the program is a spit out a unique 4 digit number and had a note if necessary.  The trouble came up with I tried to serialize the data so that when the application was opened again I would be able to load the data from where I left off.

Here is the code for the Swing Portion:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author marcsantiago
 */
public class MainForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form MainForm
     */
    public MainForm() {
        //jTextField2.setVisible(false);
        this.rndn = new RandomNumber();
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jCheckBox1 = new javax.swing.JCheckBox();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Generate Number");
        jButton1.setToolTipText("");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField1.setToolTipText("");

        jCheckBox1.setText("Add Notes");

        jButton2.setText("Save Note and Number");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("View Notes");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setEditable(false);
        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton4.setText("Save All Data");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setText("Load Data");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                            .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(112, 112, 112)
                                .addComponent(jButton3)
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(77, 77, 77)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 181, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 187, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 190, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(113, 113, 113)
                                .addComponent(jCheckBox1)))
                        .addGap(0, 82, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(111, 111, 111))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(22, 22, 22)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jCheckBox1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 106, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton4)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jButton5)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    public RandomNumber rndn;
    //View Randomly Generated Number buttom
    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        jTextField1.setText(rndn.getNumber());
    }                                        

    //save number button
    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(jCheckBox1.isSelected()){
            String text = jTextField3.getText();
            rndn.removeNumber(text);
        }else{
            rndn.removeNumber("");

        }
    }                                        

    //view notes
    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,String> entry : rndn.getSaveState().entrySet()) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            sb.append("ID: ").append(key).append("\t");
            sb.append("Note: ").append(value).append("\n");      
        }

        jTextArea1.setText(sb.toString());
    }                                        

    //save data
    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        BufferedReader txtReader = rndn.getTxtReader();
        ArrayList<String> numbers = rndn.getNumbers();
        ArrayList<String> usedNumbers = rndn.getUsedNumbers();
        String currentNumber = rndn.getCurrentNumber();
        Map<String, String> saveState = rndn.getSaveState();

        try
        {
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/data.ser");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(rndn);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();

        }catch(IOException i)
        {
          i.printStackTrace();
        }

    }                                        

    //load data
    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
//        try
//        {
//            FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("/tmp/data.ser");
//            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
//            rndn = (RandomNumber) in.readObject();
//            in.close();
//            fileIn.close();
//        }catch(IOException i)
//        {
//            i.printStackTrace();
//            return;
//        }catch(ClassNotFoundException c)
//        {
//            System.out.println("Employee class not found");
//            c.printStackTrace();
//            return;
//        }
//        System.out.println(rndn.getSaveState());
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(MainForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MainForm().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JCheckBox jCheckBox1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

near the end I've comment the two methods as //save and //load
That those methods I can't figure out. When I try and serialize the rndn object I get this error: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.io.BufferedReader
The class that contains the data is serrate from the Form Class:
Here is the RandomNumber class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author marcsantiago
 */
public class RandomNumber implements java.io.Serializable{
    private BufferedReader txtReader;
    private ArrayList<String> numbers;
    private ArrayList<String> usedNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    private Random rnd = new Random();
    private String currentNumber;
    private Map<String, String> saveState = new HashMap<>();

    RandomNumber(){
        this.txtReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(RandomNumber.class.getResourceAsStream("/resources/unique_nums"))); 
        try{
            numbers = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(txtReader.readLine().split(",")));
        }catch(IOException e){

        }
    }

    public String getNumber(){

        int item = rnd.nextInt(numbers.size());
        currentNumber = numbers.get(item);
        while(usedNumbers.contains(currentNumber)){
            item = rnd.nextInt(numbers.size());
            currentNumber = numbers.get(item);
        }
        return currentNumber;
    }

    public void removeNumber(String note){
        usedNumbers.add(currentNumber);
        saveState.put(currentNumber, note);
        numbers.remove(currentNumber);
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getUsedNumbers() {
        return usedNumbers;
    }

    public String getCurrentNumber() {
        return currentNumber;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getSaveState() {
        return saveState;
    }

    public void setTxtReader(BufferedReader txtReader) {
        this.txtReader = txtReader;
    }

    public BufferedReader getTxtReader() {
        return txtReader;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getNumbers() {
        return numbers;
    }

    public Random getRnd() {
        return rnd;
    }

    public void setNumbers(ArrayList<String> numbers) {
        this.numbers = numbers;
    }

    public void setUsedNumbers(ArrayList<String> usedNumbers) {
        this.usedNumbers = usedNumbers;
    }

    public void setRnd(Random rnd) {
        this.rnd = rnd;
    }

    public void setCurrentNumber(String currentNumber) {
        this.currentNumber = currentNumber;
    }

    public void setSaveState(Map<String, String> saveState) {
        this.saveState = saveState;
    }



}
```

Sorry if it's a bit messy, I haven't cleaned up the code yet because I haven't gotten it to work the way I want to to.  Any help in completing this application is much appreciated.

Comment: Object serialization is a poor (and out-dated) choice.  Consider using something like [Introduction to JAXB](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) and [for example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BufferedReader` in your class is not seriablizeable and that should be causing the issue. Make it `transient` and it should work.